# Building a fully independent wireshark dissector module in C++

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I want to build an independent Wireshark dissector module that I can recompile and use on various platforms like Android (using NDK).

To do this, I've selected some of the Wireshark source files and applied my changes. Now I have a full C and C++ module compiled with the C++ compiler in the Qt ide and in Ubuntu, which itself consists of a series of .h and .cpp files (with my custom changes) and a series of .h and .cpp files which I have written from scratch.

This module links to a large number of Wireshark header files as well as three Wireshark libraries, namely libwireshark.so and libwiretap.so and libwsutil.so, which I put the required header files in a folder and libraries in a another folder and set them alongside the project and the project is executed correctly. Since this module is based on Wireshark, it also has some dependencies on glib and some other libraries that are already available in Ubuntu. These libraries include the following with the command `ldd myApp`.

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffcaccf8000)
libwireshark.so.7 => /usr/local/lib/libwireshark.so.7 (0x00007f7d6f561000)
libwsutil.so.6 => /usr/local/lib/libwsutil.so.6 (0x00007f7d6f33e000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f7d6efb5000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f7d6ed9d000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f7d6e9ac000)
liblua5.2.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblua5.2.so.0 (0x00007f7d6e77a000)
libgcrypt.so.20 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x00007f7d6e45f000)
libgnutls.so.30 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30 (0x00007f7d6e0fa000)
libkrb5.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007f7d6de24000)
libk5crypto.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007f7d6dbf2000)
libwiretap.so.5 => /usr/local/lib/libwiretap.so.5 (0x00007f7d6d90f000)
libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f7d6d70b000)
libglib-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f7d6d3f5000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f7d6d1d8000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f7d6ce3a000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f7d6cc1b000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f7d743f9000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f7d6ca17000)
libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007f7d6c802000)
libp11-kit.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0 (0x00007f7d6c4d3000)
libidn2.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn2.so.0 (0x00007f7d6c2b6000)
libunistring.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunistring.so.2 (0x00007f7d6bf38000)
libtasn1.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6 (0x00007f7d6bd25000)
libnettle.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.6 (0x00007f7d6baef000)
libhogweed.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.4 (0x00007f7d6b8bb000)
libgmp.so.10 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10 (0x00007f7d6b63a000)
libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007f7d6b436000)
libkrb5support.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007f7d6b22b000)
libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007f7d6b027000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f7d6ae0c000)
libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f7d6ab9a000)
libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0x00007f7d6a992000)
```

As I said at the beginning of my question, my goal is to make this module completely independent and capable of being recompiled and used on other platforms like Android. Now, my question is that is this independence arises by putting all these libraries on the top alongside the project? If not, what is the solution? Is there a similar program to get help (like [Signal guru](https://signal-guru.com/) but this is not open source)?

Comment: If your dissector is compiled, the shared library itself cannot be cross-platform. You can write cross-platform code and compile separate library files for each platform, but it's a lot of work. It'd probably be easier to just write a lua dissector.

Comment: @Useless thanks, my dissector is compiled in Ubuntu but I don't want to use the shared library obtained from my dissector in other platforms. I want to compile again my module (including some .h and .cpp with some .so files) in other platforms like android using NDK.

Comment: Writing cross-platform code isn't trivial, but you can give it a try by just cross-compiling for another platform, fixing errors as they come up, and then figuring out how to keep your code working for both targets. You will have to figure out which libraries you really need, and which are available on what platforms, as you go.

Comment: @Useless As I want to use my module in android with NDK, I know that I can probably attach my module to an android app. I want to know that will I intrinsically have an independent program if I put the mentioned libs to my module?

Comment: Linking for android will use different (android) libs, and they will have different (android) dependencies. You need to actually build the android version first and then figure out what dependencies it has, and _then_ worry about how to package them.

Comment: @Useless thanks again, do you mean that I need to build the android version in Qt and export shared library? or in android studio ide?